# Playing transport stream MediaPlayer android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, transport-stream

I have to try to play a .ts video using a MediaPlayer but it seems that is not capable.

```
 @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

    try {
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(URI));
    mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

My tests are in devices over Android  4 but I have found these references 
[URL1](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html),
[URL2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html)
and if I play the .ts video in VLC, for example, there is no problem.

I have tested the same code in two devices, one STB with android 4.0.4 and the other is a tablet ASUS Transformer TF101 with an `android 4.0.3`. It works in the STB but no in the ASUS Transformer.
What would be the difference?

Thanks in advance for your time!
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't about the .ts encapsulation, the problem was in the codification of the video. It had MPEG-2 video codification but it's not supported by default on Android.